# Rails - Rake error: Library not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dylib, loaded

I have read just about every post regarding rails errors looking for the solution to my issues and while I have resolved some, I come up with more.  I upgraded to Snow Leopard and installed RVM and Rails according to the Agile Development with Rails book.  However once I create my app folders and do RAKE, I get this error and I just can not figure out how to fix it. I've tried re-installing everything several times to no avail.  Is this an architecture problem? or do I need to find a library and load it? how do I do that?

```
rake aborted!
dlopen(/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9/digest/sha1.bundle
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9/digest/sha1.bundle

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 6):

There was probably a change in your system. You might have moved or deleted some files or folders, which were needed by ruby.

```
rvm reinstall ree
```

Or spyle's answer is basically correct, but ewww macports. go go Homebrew!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with ruby 1.8.7/passenger/apache stack. Reinstalling ruby (via macports) and rebuilding it against the openssl library fixed this for me.