# bundle install Library not loaded error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, homebrew

Environment:

- Rails 3.2.11
- Heroku bamboo-mri-1.9.2
- Using RVM
- ruby-1.9.2-p290

my .rvmrc is configured to use ruby-1.9.2-p290

When running the `bundle install` command, I am getting this:

```
/Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': dlopen(/Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:245:in `install'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

TRY 1

```
rvm pkg install openssl

rvm reinstall all --force
```

then cd .. and cd project_folder

```
bundle install
```

All gem install again properly

the first error is gone
BUT when I move into another project using ruby 1.9.3, I get a 'new' error, so it seems like I won't be able to use at the same time 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 ... or I'll have to reinstall my gems everytime ??? I must missing something.

here the new error:

```
/Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': dlopen(/Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rb_Digest_SHA1_Finish (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle - /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:301:in `update'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@creativebank/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@creativebank/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Does `/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` exist?

Comment: Do either of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11231902/877472) help?

Comment: @mipadi no that library doesn't exist and I have been trying to figure out if it's installed any other place.

Comment: @Teeg no those answers didn't help. I have recently moved from MacPorts to HomeBrew. Also bundle install works fine if using Ruby 1.9.3 but I need 1.9.2

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned you recently moved from MacPorts to Homebrew, I'd say it's likely that you had some gems that were compiled against a MacPorts-installed library (`in /opt/local`) that doesn't exist anymore. You should recompile those gems to link against the Homebrew-supplied versions of those libraries (or the Apple ones, if they exist). You can recompile a gem with native components simply be re-installing it.